# A list of derived classes of a virtual base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, vectorization, subclass

I tried to create a base virtual class "Shape" with 2 methods in it. Below I have created 3 subclasses who inherit from the base class. In the main function I created 3 instances, one per subclass and I would like to have a list of all subclasses created from my base class, the list should be sortable by either one of the virtual methods defined in the base class.

I tried to implement the list library based on some examples from the internet but I don't understand it well enough to make it work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <conio.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Shape
{
protected:
int value_;

public:
   /*static list<Shape*> instances_;
   Shape(int val);
   static void showList();*/
   virtual void surface()=0;
   virtual void circuit()=0;

};

/*Shape::Shape(int val) {
   instances_.push_back(this);
   value_ = val;}

list<Shape*> Shape::instances_;

void Shape::showList() {
   for (list<Shape*>::iterator p = instances_.begin();
        p != instances_.end(); ++p)
      cout << (*p)->value_ << endl;}*/
//////////////////////////////////

class Circle :public Shape
{
   float r;
public:
   Circle(float x)
   {
      r=x;
   }
   virtual void surface()
   {
      cout<<"Circle surface: "<<3.14*r*r<<endl;
   }
   virtual void circuit(){
      cout<<"Circle circuit: "<<3.14*2*r<<endl;
   }
};
////////////////////////////////////////

class Square:public Shape
{
   float a;
public:
   Square:public (float x)
   {
      a=x;
   }
   virtual void surface()
   {
      cout<<"Square surface: "<<a*a<<endl;
   }
    virtual void circuit(){
      cout<<"Square circuit : "<<4*a<<endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
    Circle k(8);
    Square kw(2);


   return 0;
};
```

Comment: Half of that is commented out. Convert it to a minimal example that shows your problem.

Comment: Beside the fact that you should definitely read about virtual destructors and the 'override' keyword, what is it exactly you want to achieve ? A list of classes ? What does that mean ?

Comment: Do you want a list of classes or a list of instances? What are you trying to achieve with that? This is all very unclear. As general advise, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I would like to have a sortable  list of all instances of any child class(Circle, Square). 

I commented out my attempts to make it work using lst library.

Comment: please show your attempt. You have a `std::vector<Shape*>` ?

Comment: Part of the point of polymorphism - if used well - is that the base class doesn't need to know anything about classes derived from it.   Expecting a base class to list all derived classes, or even instances of derived classes, clashes with good practice in a bad way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things in this code that can be improved. However, it is essential that you understand the concepts of inheritance, polymorphism and the crude details behind implementing polymorphism in C++.

For example: A default base class destructor is not automatically virtual. You need to specify a virtual base class destructor when you intend to implement a polymorphic structure. Derived classes *are* automatically set to virtual iff (if and only if) the base class has a virtual destructor.

To sort a list of Shapes you first need to create a list of `Shape*`. Then you need to write a comparison function which will take 2 shapes and use one of their members to compare them. In your example, there was nothing to use. Both of the member functions were `void` and the member variables were private.

See the code below and hopefully it will make sense.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>

struct Shape
{
    Shape() = default;

    virtual float surface() const = 0;
    virtual void circuit() = 0;

    virtual ~Shape() noexcept = default;
};

class Circle final : public Shape
{
    private:
        float r;

    public:
        Circle(float r_) : r(r_)
        {;}

        float surface() const override
        {
            return M_PI*pow(r,2);
        }

        void circuit() override
        {
            std::cout<<"Circle circuit: " << 2.f*M_PI*r <<std::endl;
        }

        ~Circle() noexcept = default;
};

class Square final : public Shape
{
    private:
        float a;

    public:
        Square(float a_) : a(a_)
        {;}

        float surface() const override
        {
            return pow(a,2);
        }

        void circuit() override
        {
            std::cout<<"Square circuit: " << 4.f*a <<std::endl;
        }

        ~Square() noexcept = default;
};


bool compare_shape(const Shape *const s1, const Shape *const s2)
{
    return (s1->surface() < s2->surface());
}

int main()
{
    // no polymorphism
    Circle c(8);
    std::cout<< "Circle surface: " << c.surface() <<std::endl;
    c.circuit();

    Square s(2);
    std::cout<< "Square surface: " << s.surface() <<std::endl;
    s.circuit();

    std::cout<< "____________________" <<std::endl<<std::endl;

    // polymorphism
    Shape *c_ptr = new Circle(8);
    std::cout<< "Circle surface: " << c_ptr->surface() <<std::endl;
    c_ptr->circuit();
    delete c_ptr;

    Shape *s_ptr = new Square(2);
    std::cout<< "Square surface: " << s_ptr->surface() <<std::endl;
    s_ptr->circuit();
    delete s_ptr;

    std::cout<< "____________________" <<std::endl<<std::endl;

    // list of Shapes
    std::list<Shape*> shapes;
    shapes.push_back( new Circle(8) );
    shapes.push_back( new Square(2) );

    for (auto &&i : shapes)
    {
        std::cout<< "Shapes' surface: " << i->surface() <<std::endl;
        i->circuit();
    }

    std::cout<< "\n-- sorting the list based on the shapes' surface.\n" <<std::endl;
    shapes.sort(compare_shape);

    for (auto &&i : shapes)
    {
        std::cout<< "Shapes' surface: " << i->surface() <<std::endl;
        i->circuit();
    }
};
```

Online code example: https://rextester.com/EBKIH52610

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do sorting in a polymorphic manner, search documentation on overloading the `bool operator<()' method. To compare types you could use the 'typeid' operator.